# deselect struts2 select from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

how can I deselect struts2 select list from javascripts?

eg.

```
<s:select name="bookIds" list="bookList" listKey="key"
          listValue="value" multiple="true" theme="simple"
          onchange="getVal(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'myvalue');"/>
```

I want to deselect all the list after onchange event.

Comment: If you deselect everything after selecting something, how will you select something?

Comment: after each selection, will keep the value of previous selected items in hidden values. for my case, there will be 4 section, each has a select list box like above. My problem is I select items in select box of section 1 and then select the items in another select box of section2. Previously selected items in section 1 keep selected. That's why I want to deselect items after each event.

Comment: How will you de-select? In any case, just write a method to call from the onclick that uses normal JavaScript to unset any of the select element's values--search for "javascript clear select choices" or something.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `headerKey` and `headerValue`

```
<s:select id="book_select" name="bookIds" list="bookList" listKey="key"
          headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Book"
          listValue="value" multiple="true" theme="simple"
          onchange="getVal(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'myvalue');"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getVal(myvalue){
//do your stuff
document.getElementById("book_select").value="-1";
}
```

I also suggest that instead of storing the selected values in a hidden field you must show them in some div, otherwise users may get confuse and keep on selecting the same values again and again.